# Edge loop select does not work!

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I have a problem i cant select edge loops. I have already reinstalled Blender and restored factory settings.  Alt+RMB and Select->Edge Loops dont work. Any idea why?(i am running it on Win10)

Comment: loop select has been around forever, so it's not a bug, it's probably your mouse (or alt key on keyboard), have you tried swapping mice/keyboards.

Comment: Uploading one (or more)screenshots, and uploading you blend file to Blend exchange (or a similar site) woul be of great use to those who might want to help you.

Comment: You may be in Face Selection mode. See here: [Can't Select Edge Loop - Alt + RMB is Failing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/cant-select-edge-loop-alt-rmb-is-failing)

Comment: Loop select follows quads. A failure is often a useful clue to hidden edges.. doubles, other ways in which the geometry is not the way it looks

Answer (score 1):

[Can't select Edge loop (Alt + RMB is failing )](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/cant-select-edge-loop-alt-rmb-is-failing/112232#112232)

Try to turn off "Emulate 3 Button Mouse"

You can find it at:

-> File

-> User Preferences(Ctrl + Alt + U)

-> Input

-> Mouse: Emulate 3 Button Mouse(OFF)

-> Press "Save user Settings"

[image]