# Can't create vertex loop

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm following a video tutorial by Blender Guru and everything has been all right except I can't select a vertex loop or select any other through the shortcut of pressing alt and clicking the vertex. 
What does work is that when I choose the edge selection and click on the edge loop button, it works but only for the edge selection. It doesn't work for the face or vertex selection.

Is this because I don't have a mouse with my laptop?

Comment: This may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/cant-select-edge-loop-alt-rmb-is-failing I don't know if this is your exact problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: could you post an image? or the file?